# Web App for Containers - Kudu omitting Docker Login

Tags: azure, docker, web-applications, containers, kudu

We use Web App for Containers to operate Docker containers hosted on our Azure registry. This web app has been configured to pull the latest changes from the registry which in turns has lead to the creation of the following env variables:

- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME
- DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD
- DOCKER_ENABLE_CI

All values are correct and in the first place the Docker based setup worked well for us. Since monday, however, Kudu is longer able to pull docker images from our registry (neither from any registry that requires auth at all). The Kudu log is:

```
docker pull returned STDERR>> Error response from daemon: Get OUR_REGISTRY: unauthorized: authentication required
```

which suggests that Kudu is omitting the required Docker login call. Has anyone observed the same behaviour or is aware of Azure changes that require any adoption form our site. Thanks!

What we have tried so far:

- creating a new registry
- creating a new web app
- creating a new service plan
- restarting/stopping the web apps

Comment: Did you ever solve your issue? If so, how were you able to work around this issue?